# Script version number causes undefined variables

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript file that is loaded with a version parameter, to cause it to reload every time I change it.

```html
<script type="module" src="js/main.js?20190327-1"></script>
```

Sometimes I try to access a variable and I get an undefined error. I print the variable to the console and I have the following result (Line 703 is the set of the variable and line 279 is the get):

[image]

I called the same thing twice and the second time it seems to work. What I noticed is that it changes the file name from "main.js" to "main.js?20190327-1".

I removed the version from the src and it seems to work fine.
[image]

Am I missing something with the usage of the version parameter? Is there any other way I could force the browser to reload the scripts every time a version is changed?

Thank you in advance.

---

edit:
I found out that the problem was caused by both loading as a script

```html
<script type="module" src="js/main.js?20190327-1"></script>
```

but also importing it as a module from javascript code.

```
import * as main from './js/main.js'
```

That caused the browser to load it twice. If I rename all occurrences of
`import * as main from './js/main.js'` to `import * as main from './js/main.js?20190327-1'` everything works fine. But is there any way to force it to reload without the need to rename all the imports?

Comment: There is no logical explanation for why you would see both `main.js` and `main.js?20190327-1` in the console debug statements, if you only embedded the latter into the document - browsers usually don’t make up URLs on their own. I think whatever the problem is here, is not determinable with just that one single line of HTML code you have given us.

Comment: How do you set the version name? Do you rename the file yourself or does you let you server do it (using php or something else server side)?

Comment: I change the version parameter manually.

Comment: Also "sources" tab shows two versions of the file: https://imgur.com/a/Ld6oEO5